# Advice on damaged Indian passport

Tags: passports, india

The stamp on my passport got smudged a little bit due to rainwater going in. But the information page is still intact without any damage. Also, there is a valid German visa on this passport, where I will be travelling to in October. Will this passport be considered as damaged?

[[image]

Comment: @Traveller IMO this is not a duplicate. The damage described here and in that question are different. The answers are also potentially different.

Comment: To me, this doesn't seem a problem. The damages seems only on a stamp (of India on an Indian passport), and such stamp is not something that guarantee the authenticity of the passport (there are many more security features). On the other hand, it also the visa is damaged (or countries stamps), or near photo or names, it could seem an attempt to hide tempering.

Answer (score 2):

What you have shown in the picture is a damaged passport and there is a high probability that you would be denied travelling with this passport.

There is no guideline as such about how the passport is classified as damaged by MEA and it will totally depend on the immigration officer when you travel and I don't think you will get through the immigration.

You still have sufficient time to apply for the new passport and it is not *damaged without recognition* so you can apply for re-issue of passport under the Tatkaal scheme.

Comment: Will the visa(which is still intact), which is in this passport, be valid after I get the new passport?

Comment: The damaged passport will be returned to you with the cancelled stamp when you receive your new passport. The new passport would carry the old passport number and all the visas in your old passport would be valid. You will just have to carry both the passports while travelling.

Comment: It's mentioned under EC regulation: The cancellation of a travel document by an authority of a third country does not mean that the uniform visa affixed to that document is automatically invalidated.